# Textbook question regarding LTI System

Tags: linear-systems, homework

I was posed the following homework problem:

> **2.10** The following input-output pairs have been observed during the operation of a time-invariant system:
>   \begin{align}
> x_1(n)&=\{\underset{\uparrow}{1}, 0, 2\}\overset{\mathcal T}{\longleftrightarrow} y_1(n)=\{\underset{\uparrow}{0}, 1, 2\}\\
> x_2(n)&=\{\underset{\uparrow}{0}, 0, 3\}\overset{\mathcal T}{\longleftrightarrow} y_2(n)=\{\underset{\uparrow}{0}, 1, 0, 2\}\\
> x_3(n)&=\{\underset{\uparrow}{0}, 0, 0,1\}\overset{\mathcal T}{\longleftrightarrow} y_3(n)=\{1,\underset{\uparrow}{2}, 1\}\\
> \end{align}
>   Can you draw any conclusions regarding the linearity of the system ? What is the impulse response of the system ?

I thought that I had a decent grasp on linearity and time-invariance, but I am having trouble relating them to a specific problem.  I know that linearity means that the system satisfies the superposition principle - and that the weighted sum of the input signals is equal to the weighted sum to each output signal.

How do I apply that to this problem?  I have the solution below, but I am unsure how they get there:

> **2.10**
>
> The system is nonlinear. This is evident form observation of the pairs
>   $$x_3(n)\leftrightarrow y_3 (n)\text{ and }x_2(n)\leftrightarrow y_2(n).$$
>   If the system were linear, $y_2(n)$ would be of the form
>   $$y_2(n)=\{3, 6, 3\}$$
>   because the system is time-invariant. However, this is not the case.

Comment: What is the meaning of the vertical arrow pointing up?

Comment: It means that is the point where n = 0.  Essentially giving you an idea of where the graph starts/ends on the discrete plot.

Comment: which way does time go? is n=1 left or right from the vertical arrow? I gotta say, this is a quirky notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that the system is time invariant, then a  shift to the right of $x_2$, say $$x^s_2 = \{\underset{\uparrow}{0}, 0,0, 3\}$$ should give you the shifted version of $y_2(n)$, in other words:  $$y^s_2(n)=\{\underset{\uparrow}{0}, 0, 1, 0, 2\}\,.$$ But $x^s_2 = 3 x_3$ (a linear factor), and $y^s_2$ is not a multiple of $y_3$. Linearity is not preserved.

One example of non-linearity suffices to claim the system cannot be both time-invariant and linear.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a very contrived question, but the idea is simple: if the system were linear, then, since $x_2[n]=3x_3[n+1]$, then $y_2[n]$ should be $3y_3[n+1]$. The impulse response can be obtained by time-shifting $x_3$ so that the $1$ is at $n=0$, and then time-shift $y_3$ the same amount.